# Access environment variables in CI context from poetry virtualenv

Tags: python, python-poetry

I'm using gitlab CI and set a couple of environment variables which I need to import in python. Apparently, these are not available when I use poetry.
Is there a simple way to make environment variables accessible within the virtualenv that poetry created?

Edit: My bad! I stumbled accross a bad software design decision. For reference check the comment of @finswimmer.

Comment: How do you set the env variables and how do you run your program? poetry will not load any `.env` file for you, but any env var already loaded can be access normally, e.g. `TEST="SOMETEST" poetry run python -c "import os;print(os.environ['TEST'])"`